# Error when using DateAdd on a parameter in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to set a range of dates. I receive a parameter called @EffectiveDate and i want to set a range from 3 years prior to the effective date.

As an example. This is working code.

```
CStr(Format(CDate(DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -3, Today())),"yyyy"))
```

But when I try to use the parameter like below

```
=CStr(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -3, CDate(Parameters!EffectiveDate.Value)),"yyyy"))
```

I get an error. I don't know what the error is. All i see is #Error when running the report.

The parameter is set up as "Date/Time" in SSRS and I even convert it just incase.

The following code does work though

```
=CStr(Format(CDate(Parameters!EffectiveDate.Value),"yyyy"))
```

So it does seem like it is the "DateAdd" method

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It looks like it should be working. If you run the report in Visual Studio, you should get a *somewhat* helpful error message in the **Error List** window that might narrow down which function has an issue. The FORMAT is already converting to string so CSTR should be unnecessary.

Comment: I would troubleshoot by eliminating all the functions and add them one at a time till you get an error. First just the EffectiveDate parameter, then add the CDATE, then (if that works) the DateAdd Function, then format, CSTR... You could also try `CSTR(YEAR(Parameters!EffectiveDate.Value) - 3)`

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this code

=CStr(Format(CDate(DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -3, CDate(Parameters!EffectiveDate.Value))),"yyyy"))

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works

```
=CStr(Format(CDate(DateAdd("yyyy", -3, Now())), "yyyy"))  'Result =2015
```

and if this works try it with your **Parameter** (instead of *Now()*). If it doesnt work then, something is wrong with your **Parameter**